# Is it possible to include_recipe without adding the recipe do metadata.rb

Tags: chef-infra, cookbook, recipe

I have a cookbook that needs to install software for both Windows and RHEL boxes. There is an existing cookbook I can leverage for the RHEL boxes, which I'll call `linux-foo`. I include it in the default recipe with `include_recipe 'linux-foo'` and add with `depends 'linux-foo'` in the cookbook metadata.

However, by adding the dependency to metadata it's breaking my custom Windows recipe. I'm getting

```
   NoMethodError
   -------------
   undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

   Platform:
   ---------
   x64-mingw32
```

when attempting to converge the windows recipe in test-kitchen. It's referring to the `.../linux-foo/attributes/default.rb` as the culprit, but doesn't specify which attribute.

Is there a way to still `include_recipe 'linux-foo'` but not include it as a hard dependency in `metadata.rb` OR wrap the 3rd party cookbook's default attributes somehow?

It looks like I either keep the dependency and break the windows recipe or separate the linux and windows recipes into separate cookbooks.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no direct way to do this. Chef does not support optional dependencies at this time.

The best fix is to make your `linux-foo` cookbook safe to load on non-Linux machines, even if the recipes aren't. If you look in the file mentioned in the error report you can find the full stack trace, that will tell you which line needs fixing (though there may be more than one).

Comment: Thanks @coderanger. I checked the stacktrace dumped on the VM and it was pretty cryptic but I'll revisit that. In what ways can I make the third party `linux-foo` cookbook safe and compatible with my windows recipe? Can I somehow wrap or guard its problematic default attributes in my cookbook?